# Keep getting an empty JSON object

Tags: java, jquery, json

Hi I'm new to JSON and I've been trying to get my List into a JSONArray, so that I can use it later with JQuery and include it on a website, but it keeps returning an empty array. I'm using Java EE and wrote a named query, I'm not too sure that the named query is the thief behind it. Here's most probably the appropiate code I hope.

The named query in Review.class:

@NamedQueries ({

```
@NamedQuery(name="Review.findByTitleOrName", query = "SELECT r FROM Review r WHERE r.artist.artistNr = (SELECT a.artistNr FROM Artist a WHERE a.artistName Like :A) OR r.track.trackID = (SELECT t.trackID FROM Track t WHERE t.trackTitle LIKE :A)")
})
```

Method in the EAO for reviews that should work:

```
public List<Review> getReviewsByTitleOrName(String searchParameter) {
        TypedQuery<Review> tq = em.createNamedQuery("Review.findByTitleOrName", Review.class);

        tq.setParameter("A", searchParameter); 

        List<Review> reviewList = tq.getResultList();
        return reviewList;
    }
```

Servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");

        JsonArrayBuilder arrayOfJsonReviews = Json.createArrayBuilder();

        String searchParameter = request.getParameter("ajax_searchParameter");
        List<Review> reviews = facade.getReviewsByTitleOrName(searchParameter);


        for(Review r : reviews){
            JsonObjectBuilder review = Json.createObjectBuilder();
            review.add("date", r.getDate());
            review.add("comment", r.getComments());
            review.add("rating", r.getRating());
            review.add("user", r.getUserName());
            arrayOfJsonReviews.add(review);
        }

        response.getWriter().write(arrayOfJsonReviews.build().toString());
    }
```

And last but not least the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".SearchBtn").click(function() {
        console.log("Clicked button");
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/DynamicDolphinProject/DolphinServlet", function(data){
            console.log(data);
            //placeReviewDat(data);
            console.log("Should have data");
        });
    });

    //function placeReviewData(reviews){

    //}
})
```

Comment: What is the console output when you call console.log(data)?

Comment: Can you check the response in the console? Maybe the mime type is not properly set?

Comment: @BenjaminRay the output is simply [] which is an empty array right?

Answer (score 0):

These builders are problematic, I had similar issue with arrayBuilder. The solution seems to be to build object earlier and then return the value.

in my case it was like this:

```
        JsonArrayBuilder itemArrayBuilder = factory.createArrayBuilder();

        for (Result<Item> result : results) {
            try {
                Item item = result.get();
                itemArrayBuilder.add(factory.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("name", item.objectName())
                .add("isdir", item.isDir())
                );
            } catch (InvalidKeyException | ErrorResponseException | IllegalArgumentException | InsufficientDataException
                    | InternalException | InvalidResponseException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | ServerException
                    | XmlParserException | IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // build first
        JsonArray jsonArray = itemArrayBuilder.build();
        System.out.println("jsonArray:" + jsonArray);
        return jsonArray;
```

Then it worked. If I just had `return itemArrayBuilder.build();` it returned empty array.